# Istio/Envoy access logs to a persistent volume

Tags: logging, istio, envoyproxy

How can Istio/Envoy be configured to keep writing access logs (ingress) to files in a persistent volume?Different pods responding to a same hostname (example.com) would be writen to the same file.
I think it would be something defined in Gateway YAML file or VirtualService YAML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by combination of settings up the `EnvoyFilter` configuration to selectively enable access logs at gateways and use `custom-bootstrap-config`:

1. First you would need to setup custom bootstrap configuration that will container your `user-volumes` and `volume mounts`. This config later on can be applied with `kubectl patch` as described [here](https://istio.io/latest/news/security/istio-security-2020-007/#mitigation).

   References:
   https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/28302
2. The next step would to use `EnvoyFilter` configuration to selectively enable access logs at gateways as described in [Tracing and Access Log](Use EnvoyFilter configuration to selectively enable access logs at gateways).  By default logs are directed to `/dev/stdout`. This has to be change appropriately to match the volume you configured in the step 1 with custom bootstrap config.

   References:
   https://github.com/istio/istio/wiki/EnvoyFilter-Samples#tracing-and-access-logging

Comment: I know using files for access logs might not be the best practice but your answer was what I was looking for. What would be the best practice to manage access logs? Elasticsearch, Fluentd and Kibana (EFK) ?